# What is the difference between services.Configure() and services.AddOptions<T>().Bind() when loading configuration in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

In my ASP.NET Core 2.2 WebApi project, I want to load configuration from `appsettings.json` into strongly typed object.

The appsettings.json has following configuration section:

```json
{
  "MySettings1": {
    "Name": "John Smith",
    "Age": "25",
  }
}
```

which I want to load into strongly typed object `MySettings`:

```cs
public class MySettings
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

I can do this in my `Startup.ConfigureServices()` method either like this:

```cs
services.Configure<MySettings>(configuration.GetSection("MySettings1"));
```

or like this:

```cs
services.AddOptions<MySettings>().Bind(configuration.GetSection("MySettings1"));
```

What is the difference between these two approaches? Both of them work fine as I am able to get proper instance of `IOptions<MySettings>` injected in `HomeController` in both cases.

Are there some specific scenarios in which I should use one over the other approach? (for example, in the future I will probably want to add some kind of runtime validation of the MySettings object once it's populated from the configuration, so in this case should I prefer one approach over the other?)

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: To add more confusing, we also have `services.Configure<MySettings>(o => configuration.Bind("MySettings1", o));`.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

This was asked in a Github issue in November 2018 [Question: AddOptions() vs. Multiple Configure(…)](https://github.com/aspnet/Extensions/issues/514). Both methods do the same job but `AddOptions` came later and allows more customizations.

> Configure(Action configureOptions) and OptionsBuilder.Configure(Action configureOptions) will both end up doing the same thing:

```
services.AddSingleton<IConfigureOptions<TOptions>>(
    new ConfigureNamedOptions<TOptions>(name, configureOptions));
```

> And OptionsBuilder.Bind(IConfiguration config) will actually call Configure(IConfiguration config) directly, so they are also equivalent.
>
> So both APIs are interchangeable. And you can expect the services.Configure calls to continue to work. The options builder API came later to allow for a bit more control with various utility methods. But it’s not a replacement for the direct services.Configure API.

Answer (score 9):

im not sure when this feature was added but using `AddOptions` exposes validation of the settings class using data annotations.

of particular value is the `ValidateOnStart` method that will perform validation during startup so issues can be caught immediately. if this isnt used then you can run into misconfiguration issues at runtime.

[docs on validation using OptionsBuilder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-7.0#options-validation)